# How do I make both dvi ports to work to support two monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I need to use two monitors on my Dell desktop computer with Windows 7. But I have difficulty to plug one of the monitors to the correct video port!

I have a VGA port on one board which I can connect either of two monitors to this port separately. On the second board I have three ports, a VGA, DVI and a HDMI port. It seems that this port is not recognized by my system. How can I make sure if it is detected?